# Error message "statement aborts at 10" in PhoneGap android App with cache manifest

Tags: android, html, cordova, cache-manifest

I am developing an Android App using PhoneGap. The App receives the frontend data fron a backend on the internet and make it an offline app using cache manifest. This worked for half a year now perfectly, but now, if the app is trying to update, it downloads everything but at the end, I get the error

```
03-24 19:42:41.304: E/SQLiteLog(2951): (13) statement aborts at 10: [INSERT INTO CacheResourceData (data, path) VALUES (?, ?)] 
03-24 19:42:41.304: E/SQLiteLog(2951): (1) statement aborts at 2: [ROLLBACK] cannot rollback - no transaction is active
```

on the LogCat logs. Dose anyone now, what this means, what the problem is and maybe, how I can solve this? The `AppCacheMaxSize` is already set to `100MB` and this is much more then the application really needs.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there is simply too much data in the database to handle.

The error 10 status code means that `A lock for the transaction could not be obtained in a reasonable time.` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/IDBDatabaseException).

Comment: Danke, damit habe ich zumindest einen neuen Ansatz wonach ich suchen kann. Hat vielleicht jemand eine Idee wie ich diesen Fehler in PhoneGap vermeiden kann ohne die externen Daten zu minimieren?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by increasing the appCache limit.

Put this code in your [appName].java at the end of your `onCreate` method.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 7) {
    //set custom cache size (20 MB), as the default seems to be to small (5 MB)
    //this is deprecated since API 18 but seems still to be needed
    super.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*20);
}
```

Unfortunately this method is deprecated since version 18. But it is still needed to get my app work with appCache at the moment. Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheMaxSize(long)